# Debugging in android studio without break points

Tags: android

I am working with Navigation drawer template on android studio 1.5, I want to check how the codes work. Being new i am not entirely sure where to set the break points. I am currently using my own physical device as an emulator and would like to debug when any text view or any item is pressed on my screen without setting up the break points. For example if i am pressing a button on my device i want android studio to stop at On click method of the button and so on.

I tried setting break points manually but it gets more confusing.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Question is why do you want to stop at onclick method?. do you want to check some states i.e variable values or anything else like that. You can Toast these values by Using Toast method, it will display your required values on the screen without any break. This may help you

Comment: I want to check how the codes work. Just like a monitor mode of debugging. When i would click on something it would automatically stop on a particular method. I think it was possible in old VISUAL BASIC 6.

Comment: You need to use breakpoints then, there's no other way.

Comment: Thank you Abdul. I finally get it.